# SQL get data with the most recent date

Tags: sql, databricks

Here is an example of the table I have:

| _id | updatedAtDate |
| --- | --- |
| ab | 2023-02-25 02:43:49 |
| ab | 2023-02-25 02:43:49 |
| ac | 2023-06-25 02:43:49 |
| ab | 2023-02-22 03:43:49 |
| ac | 2023-06-25 02:43:49 |
| ac | 2023-12-25 02:43:49 |

What I need to accomplish is to get a table with _id that have the most recent date.

Here how result should look like

| _id | updatedAtDate |
| --- | --- |
| ab | 2023-02-25 02:43:49 |
| ab | 2023-02-25 02:43:49 |
| ac | 2023-06-25 02:43:49 |
| ac | 2023-06-25 02:43:49 |

Comment: And what query have you tried?

Comment: I was trying to use an answer from here, but didn't work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383488/sql-get-most-recent-date

I guess some syntax error that I'm not aware of. I mean, databricks is slightly different

Comment: So in general, I'm out of options that I have in my knowledge

Comment: `select _id from table_name order by updatedAtDate desc limit 1` should give you what you need.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, cause I need table and ids with the most recent date. Not just the one id with the most recent date.
Table with rows that have the most recent date - that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Then, your question seems not to be clear, edit your question by adding sample result you needed.

Comment: I've added the results I'm looking for in a question, Ibrahim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct id , max(updatedatdate) over(partition by id order by updatedatdate desc) as updatedatdate from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done by `order by desc` clause to get most recent date.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
      _id, updatedAtDate 
FROM [tableName]
ORDER BY updatedAtDate DESC
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, cause I need table and ids with the most recent date. Not just the one id with the most recent date.
Table with rows that have the most recent date - that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Hi Dan, If you want to get more than one row then just remove `TOP 1` from query